# kafka + reading from topic log file

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a topic log file and the corresponding .index file. I would like to read the   messages in a streaming fashion and process it. How and where should I start?

1. Should I load these files to Kafka producer and read from topic?
2. Can i directly write a consumer to read data from the file and process it?

I have gone through the Kafka website and everywhere, it uses pre-built Kafka producers and consumers in the examples. So, I couldn't get enough guidance.

I want to read in streaming fashion in Java.

The text looks encrypted so i am not posting the input files.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I cannot follow. What do you exactly mean by "I have a topic log file"?

Comment: It's not encrypted. It's serialized in raw bytes, but standard consumers are deserailizing that... Otherwise, what you want is the CLI tool to dump log segments, but not clear why you're wanting these raw files

Comment: @matthias-j-sax there are two files in a folder, they are named 0000000000.index and 000000000.log. I want to read the files and do aggregate operations.

Comment: You would need to build a deserializer that understand the internal format used by Kafka. Overall, this seems to be a very special request. Those files are not designed to be consumer from any other application. As @cricket_007 pointed out, there is a dump log segments tool: this should help you read the files if you have the correct deserializers for keys and values.

Answer (score 2):

You can [dump log segments](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/System+Tools#SystemTools-DumpLogSegment) and use the deep iteration option to deserialize the data into something more readable.

If you want to "stream it", then use a standard Unix pipe to output to some other tool

> do aggregate operations

Then use Kafka Streams to actually read from the topic for all partitions rather than the single partition on that single broker